# How to get alert in flex web application when browser window is minimized?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

i have a flex web application. I want to show a pop-up window or alert when an event is received. even the browser window is minimized.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried?  What were the results?  Why are the results different than what you expected?

Comment: @amarnath Don't take my word for the Gospel, but I don't think this is going to be possible.  Web-based AS3 tends to be fairly locked down, and Adobe generally tries to keep you from getting in there and messing with stuff to any extent (such as circumventing users' window minimization).  Also a web-based SWF is generally along the lines of a single "movie" or what have you, with windows and pop-ups within pretty much being faked from what I understand (though AIR apps are a lot more liberal in both regards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to use the [desktop notifications](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) through Javascript. Use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call Javascript from AS3.
It might not work with every browser though.

Comment: Thanks fro suggesting desktop notifications. I tried implementing, they are working as expected in chrome and Mozilla but not working in IE. Tried IE 8, 9, 10. Is there any add-on available for IE as we have one for Mozilla.

Comment: Sorry, check that: http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is not possible with flex only. Since alert are just normal flash content.

Also Javascript alerts may not work.

The question is why do you need them ?

Comment: @ Adrian I am using web application which has an eventHandler for incoming messages. So now I have a requirement to display a pop-up with the message on top of all windows on user screen(even browser is minimized). I tried popManager which helps me with pop-up but only if the browser is not minimized.

Comment: @amarnath so your problem is: when you maximize the browser (back from minimized state) you see no alert (even if it was called to show the popup) or You want an alert to be displayed outside of the minimized browser that the user can always see ?

Comment: @ Adrian  I want an alert to be displayed outside of the minimized browser that the user can always see.

Comment: then this is not possible. :( sorry!